# How to create a softlink for all contents of a directory to another directory in shell scripts

Tags: shell, symlink

I currently have a folder like this:

```
root-config
└── etc
    └── default
        └── grub
└── ...
```

And I want to create a soft link for every file under `root-config` in `/` while keeping the relative structure. So `/` will now have a soft link like this:

```
/
└── etc
    └── default
        └── grub --> .../root-config/etc/default/grub
└── ...
```

I have tried running `ln -s root-config/* /` but it outputted `etc already exists`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: you want to link files but not directories?

Comment: what do you mean by `...` in `.../root-config/etc/default/grub` ? relative path?

Comment: @jhnc I meant some more directories before that that I omitted.

Comment: and yes the right thing is probably to link files, however doing `ln -s root-config/**/* /` will ignore all the directory structure and just create the links to the files all in `/`

Comment: `( cd root-config && find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for p; do echo ln -s "$PWD/${p#./}" "/${p#./}"; done' -- {} + )` ?